# How to type result of functions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript3.0

How can I create interface IFoo to type the result of calling `controller` in the following snippet in TypeScript?

I define functions as follow:

```
export const controller = ({ loggedUser }: IConArgs) => ({
  async getAll() {
     ...
  },

  async getById(id: IUserId) {
     ...
  },
  ...
});
```

I assign it in a following way:

```
controllers: {
    users: controller({ loggedUser: user })
}
```

then I call it accordingly:
`controllers.users.getAll();`

I want to do following:

```
IControllers: {
    controllers: {
       users: IFoo
    }
}
```

<strike>and</strike>

export const controller: IFoo = (...)

Inspired by [tutorial from Apollo Graphql](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/guides/access-control.html#models-auth):

Comment: Seems you should do it via generics: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Answer (score 0):

The correct type for `users` and `controller` is not the same, because `users` is the result of calling `controller`.  You could let `IFoo` be the interface for `users`:

```
interface IFoo {
    // TODO: Change `any` to correct return type
    getAll(): Promise<any>;
    getById(id: IUserId): Promise<any>;
}
```

If you wanted to annotate the type of `controller`, you could do:

```
export const controller: (args: IConArgs) => IFoo =
    ({ loggedUser }: IConArgs) => ({ ... });
```

Better, annotate the return type of the arrow function instead to avoid repeating the parameter type:

```
export const controller = ({ loggedUser }: IConArgs): IFoo => ({ ... });
```

If this wasn't what you were asking for, please clarify the question.

Comment: I clarified the question. Is it better? I'm interested in typing the result of controller. Thank you for the answer anyway, you are right in the typing of controller itself.